# ImportError when trying to import a custom module in Python

Tags: python, module

*Note that I searched SO for this error and while there were many similar questions, I didn't find one that addressed this particular issue.*

I'm working on a Python module that looks like this:

```
/com
    /company
        /foo
        /bar
```

I'm editing a source file within the `bar` directory and attempting to import classes that live in the `foo` directory. I've tried importing the files the following ways:

```
from com.company.foo import *
from company.foo import *
from foo import *
import com.company.foo
import company.foo
import foo
```

Each of these produces a similar error:

```
ImportError: no module named com.company.foo
```

I have `__init__.py` files in each of the directories, including the directory that contains `com`.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here - thanks in advance for you assistance!

Comment: Your main file, is it situated in the same folder as "com"?

Comment: No, the file I'm editing is in the `bar` directory.

Comment: I mean the bootstrap file. For example "python main.py". The file that starts the whole application. Or are you using wsgi or something else which is the bootstrap?

Comment: Haven't gotten that far yet. I'm just running some test code at the end of the file in `bar` and need to import classes from `foo`.

Comment: It probably has something to do with foo not being in the path of your file in bar. Try adding the path with: "sys.path.append('/home/inkedmn/com/company')" and then import everything in foo: "from foo import *"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The directory containing `/com` needs to be on the Python path. There are a number of ways to do this:

1. At the command line, every time:
   `user@host:~$ PYTHONPATH=/path/to/whatever python some_file.py`
2. In your shell configuration (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc):
   `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/whatever`
3. In Python code (I don't recommend this, as general practice):
   `import sys
   sys.path.append('/path/to/whatever')`

As some of the commenters said, usually this is handled either by the container (`mod_wsgi`, etc) or by your bootstrap/main script (which might do something like option #3, or might be invoked in an environment set up as in options #1 or #2)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It finally saves me after hours of frustration.

Comment: I bring a complement to this answer: I solve this problem using the third but using the `os.path.abspath('..')`. This caused a problem to me because my terminal must be at the same path of the bootstrap file. Otherwise my modules could not me detected.
I'm using an separated folder containing all my `domain` classes while my `application` layer contains all Django configuration.
At the top of the `settings.py` I placed the command that I mentioned above.
I guess the best option is to store the modules path on PYTHONPATH as said by @dcrosta

Answer (score 1):

Think it's 
from .foo import * 
At least in 2.7 and up